# 'Active Records Basics' Guide ROR.org question (models-related question)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Concerning the **Active Record Basics** (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) section of the ROR.org website, I'm wondering if there is a more complete guide in terms of specifically which directories and files I need to tweak/add coding scripts to?  I can generally figure where most of the code belongs, but there are certain areas I am bit fuzzy on.

**Issue:**
*not exactly sure how to fit these into the **models** (product.rb, application.rb) folder*

- ```
  user = User.create(name: "David", occupation: "Code Artist")
  ```
- ```
  user = User.new
  user.name = "David"
  user.occupation = "Code Artist"
  ```
- ```
  user = User.new do |u|
    u.name = "David"
    u.occupation = "Code Artist"
  end
  ```

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: thank you for responding.  I'll edit the original post to include the specific issues.

Comment: To create/update database tables - you need to create [migrations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) and run them.  The other code you can run in a rails console, but not clear why you'd do that.  Suggest reading up more about Rails applications in general.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a new Rails app for study purposes. `Rails new myapp`.

Look in the 'myapp' directory and you will be able to see the basic structure.

Then use the Rails scaffold generator. `Rails g scaffold mymodel`.

This will create a bunch of files that you can look at.

Comment: Yea, I definitely intend on creating a new app.  Good point about running the scaffold generator in terminal.  I appreciate the feedback.